# How do I show white logo in dark mode in Android?

Tags: android, xml, darkmode

It's png image on Splash screen and it's located in drawable-xxxhdpi. I tried creating drawable-night-xxxhdpi and drawable-night, but it doesn't work.

*Edit - the photo changes to black when I turn on dark theme

Comment: as you wrote it's a png. The Color of the png are fix

Comment: I made an edit. The photo turns black when I put on dark mode, so it becomes invisible (because the background is also black).

Comment: you may share relevant code?